# how to test node.js http client with mocha?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have a node.js module that HTTP POSTs a JSON request,

I want to test for correct url, headers, request body and that the request is actually executed.

I'm using Mocha for a testing framework. how do I test it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [nock](https://github.com/flatiron/nock). you can intercept the http request and with certain properties

Answer (score 0):

Try [SuperTest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) in combination with [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent). All the tests from express are written with [SuperTest](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/test/support/http.js).

For example:

```
var request = require('supertest')
  , express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/user', function(req, res){
  res.send(201, { name: 'tobi' });
});

describe('GET /users', function(){
  it('respond with json', function(done){
    request(app)
      .get('/user')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(200, done);
  })
})
```

Comment: @zemirco, how do I pass a live app server to this test file? I prefer to run the test separately from server.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Sinon.js for this type of thing.

```
sinon = require 'sinon'
assert = require "assert"
describe 'client', ->
  describe '#mainRequest()', ->
    it 'should make the correct HTTP call', ->
      url = "http://some.com/api/blah?command=true"
      request = {}
      sinon.stub request, 'get', (params, cb) -> cb null, { statusCode: 200 }, "OK"
      client = new MyHttpClient request  
      client.sendRequest()
      assert.ok request.get.calledWith(url)
```

To simplify testing MyHttpClient class takes a request object as a paramter to the constructor.  If not provided, it just uses require 'request'.